# Problems with creating custom chainable query set manager

Tags: python, django

In my project I'm using code from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/562/ and I'm encountering some problems.

When I use my own ChainableQuerySetManager and try to create an object through a related object I get a recursion error.

ChainableQuerySetManager source:

```
    class ChainableQuerySetManager(models.Manager):
        def __init__(self, qs_class=models.query.QuerySet):
            super(ChainableQuerySetManager,self).__init__()
            self.queryset_class = qs_class

        def get_query_set(self):
            return self.queryset_class(self.model)

        def __getattr__(self, attr, *args):
            try:
                return getattr(self.__class__, attr, *args)
            except AttributeError:
                return getattr(self.get_query_set(), attr, *args)
```

Extended query set:

```
    class ExtendedQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

        def get_or_None(self, *args, **kwargs):
            result = None
            try:
                result = self.get(*args, **kwargs)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            return result
```

And test models:

```
    class ParentObject(models.Model):
        value = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def count_someobjects(self):
            return self.someobjects.count()

        def create_someobject_throw_related(self):
            return self.someobjects.create()

        def create_someobject(self):
            return SomeObject.objects.create(parent=self)

    class SomeObject(models.Model):
        parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentObject, related_name='someobjects')
        value = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        objects = ChainableQuerySetManager(ExtendedQuerySet)
```

Test Case looks like:

```
    class ExtendedQuerySetTests(TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.parent = ParentObject.objects.create()

        def test_create_someobject_in_parent(self):
            someobject = self.parent.create_someobject_throw_related()
```

I would appreciate your help.
Full source can be found at https://github.com/RANUX/django-simptools

Comment: I understand you are a new user... yet it might have been worth having a look around before posting your first question: for one you probably would have noticed by yourself that code is pasted (and formatted) in the questions, not linked. Having it linked to a repo is also absolutely useless: when you will have fixed the problem, the code in the repo will change, and future visitors won't be able to benefit from your question. I'm not the downvoter, but I do understand why somebody actually downvoted your question... :-|

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. Try replacing `self.__class__` with `ChainableQuerySetManager` in your query manager. I never quite sorted out exactly why this was the issue, but it did solve things for me.